# Creation and Annihilation operators of negative momenta in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

I'm studying the free Klein-Gordon field, $\phi$. You can write this field as:

$\phi(\mathbf{x}) = \int \frac{ d^{3} \mathbf{p} }{(2\pi)^{3}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 E_{\mathbf{p}} }} \left[ a_{\mathbf{p}} e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} + a_{\mathbf{p}}^{\dagger} e^{-i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} \right] $

If I make the switch in variable in the integration $\mathbf{p} \mapsto - \mathbf{p}$, the above becomes:

$\phi(\mathbf{x}) = \int \frac{ d^{3} (-\mathbf{p}) }{(2\pi)^{3}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 E_{-\mathbf{p}} }} \left[ a_{-\mathbf{p}} e^{-i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} + a_{-\mathbf{p}}^{\dagger} e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} \right] $

But $E_{-\mathbf{p}} = E_{\mathbf{p}}$ and $d^{3}(-\mathbf{p}) = - d^{3}\mathbf{p}$, which means that the above becomes:

$\phi(\mathbf{x}) = \int \frac{ d^{3} \mathbf{p} }{(2\pi)^{3}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 E_{\mathbf{p}} }} \left[(-a_{-\mathbf{p}}^{\dagger}) e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} + (-a_{-\mathbf{p}}) e^{-i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} \right] $

So as far as I can tell, comparing coefficients of the exponentials between the first and third equation gives me:

$a_{-\mathbf{p}} = - a^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}}$

$a_{-\mathbf{p}}^{\dagger} = - a_{\mathbf{p}}$

Can I interchange the above freely? Is my logic sound? This seems to tell me that destroying a particle with a momentum $\mathbf{p}$ is the same as creating a particle with momentum $-\mathbf{p}$....this doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Don't forget that changing the sign of momentum also flips the integral, so the minus signs cancel.

Comment: It is false  $d^{3}(-\mathbf{p}) = - d^{3}\mathbf{p}$, the correct identity is  $d^{3}(-\mathbf{p}) = |\det J| d^{3}\mathbf{p}$ where $J_{ab} = \frac{\partial -p_a}{\partial p_b}= - \delta_{ab}$. However the absolute value does not change the overall sign...

Comment: However you final argument is wrong. You can conclude that $f(p)=g(p)$ if $\int e^{ipx} f(p) dp = \int e^{ipx} g(p) dp $. Instead you have **two** exponentials in each of your integrals...